# Control Loaded Issue

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a control which is placed on the page. Issue is I am checking the condition on the loaded event of this control. But ViewModel data is get bind after the control is loaded. So always I get the null value in the property of this control.

Please suggest the solution.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

class of property that was bind must to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.